# pureapp: changes in software components and rerun it

Tags: eclipse

I have a pureapp frame with one software component (system plugin)
    in it. Every time i make changes in install.py, i have to "build
    with binary" and "update to test environment" and deploy the frame
    which ultimately create new instance and install other default
    plugins and the one i created (takes more than 15-20 minutes).

Is there any way to make changes to my plugin only and re-run the frame
    without redeploying the instance and other default plugins?

Answer (score 0):

found the way....
my question was about IBM pure application (not added on the site yet)..
anyway trick is to add debug component and enable 'Resumable on script error' in the frame.
when execution fails, removing dump.json will resume the operation